# Rellenar una matriz predefinida para usarla en otra clase

Tags: java, poo, eclipse, herencia, polimorfismo

Tengo 2 clases una llamada nivel donde tengo una matriz de 0´s y otra llamada tablero donde uso esta matriz para crear objetos, yo lo que quiero es que la matriz tenga enteros del 0 al 3 en indices aleatorios y de manera aleatoria, pero no sé como hacerlo. adjunto mi clase nivel y mi clase tablero

```
public class Nivel {    
    public static int[][] aparicionVirus = {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            };
} // Clase Nivel
```

esta es mi matriz de 30 x 40 la cual quiero llenar en 300 espacios aleatorios que con 1, 2 y 3 para usarla como condicional en esta otra clase que adjunto a continuacuión. Bueno es un método que está dentro de otra clase.

```
public void crearEnemigos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Nivel.aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Nivel.aparicionVirus.length; j++) {
                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 1) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaL(i * 40, j * 40));

                } // If

                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 2) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaS(i * 40, i * 40));

                } // If

                if (Nivel.aparicionVirus[i][j] == 3) {
                    casilla[i][j] = new Casilla();
                    casilla[i][j].setEnemigo(new CepaV(i * 40, j * 40));
                } // If
            } // For j
        } // For i
    } // Crear Enemigos
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrego código con comentarios:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Nivel {

   // por defecto la matriz se inicia con ceros así que no es necesario inicializarla
    public static int[][] aparicionVirus = new int[30][40];
    // el bloque static permite acceder a los miembros estáticos
    static {
        Random random = new Random();
        // iterar la matriz y colocar un número entre 0 y 3 de forma aleatoria
        for (int i = 0; i < aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < aparicionVirus[i].length; j++) {
                aparicionVirus[i][j] = random.nextInt(4);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Actualización**

Usando `Math.random()`.

`(Math.random() * ((3 - 0) + 1)) + 0;` 3 es el valor máximo y 0 es el mínimo.

```
public class Nivel {

    // por defecto la matriz se inicia con ceros así que no es necesario inicializarla
    public static int[][] aparicionVirus = new int[30][40];

    // el bloque static permite acceder a los miembros estáticos
    static {

        // iterar la matriz y colocar un número entre 0 y 3 de forma aleatoria
        for (int i = 0; i < aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < aparicionVirus[i].length; j++) {
                aparicionVirus[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * ((3 - 0) + 1)) + 0;
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

**Actualización**

Generar solo 300 números

```
public class Nivel {

   // por defecto la matriz se inicia con ceros así que no es necesario inicializarla
    public static int[][] aparicionVirus = new int[30][40];
    // el bloque static permite acceder a los miembros estáticos
    static {


        // agregar 300 números aleatorios entre 1 y 3
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < aparicionVirus[i].length; j++) {

                if(contador == 300) continue;

                aparicionVirus[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * ((3 - 1) + 1)) + 1;
                contador++;
            }
        }

        // revolver la matriz
        for (int i = 0; i < aparicionVirus.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < aparicionVirus[i].length; j++) {
                // generar indices i y j aleatorios para intercambiar los elementos
                // de la matriz
                int indexi = (int) (Math.random() * ((aparicionVirus.length  -1) + 1));
                int indexj = (int) (Math.random() * ((aparicionVirus[0].length -1 ) + 1));

                int temp = aparicionVirus[indexi][indexj];
                aparicionVirus[indexi][indexj] = aparicionVirus[i][j];
                aparicionVirus[i][j] = temp;

            }
        }
        

    }
```

Comment: me pide un import para usar Random y cuando lo uso me pide que cree una clase

Comment: Todo está completo, no debería mostrarte error.

Comment: pregunta actualizada mira

Comment: Agregué otro código usando Math.random().

Comment: eso solo me rellenará los 300 espacios? es que ocupo 300 espacios con 1,2,3 y los otros en 0

Comment: Ya actualicé, agregué un código que inserta 300 números entre 1 y 3 en los primeros 300 espacios de la matriz. Luego itera la matriz para revolver los números.